# Updating data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Say I have a column in my table which has 12 possible value.

I want to have them changed with 12 other value. For example if I have 
{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l} I'd like to change them to {z,y,x,w,...,O} .

The reason I want to change them is since the first set is written in Persian, it does not properly get found in select queries. I want to change them to their English synonyms.

What should I do?

I tried:

```
Update table one
set column = z
where column =a
```

Should I repeat this process for 12 times or there is a better way?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. If you have to change the table only ONCE, then your approach is fine. But if you have to change the table every now and then, then you should go for a more optimal and recursive approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Update table one
set column = case 
                     when column = a then z 
                     when column = b then y  
                     .....
                     when column = l then O
                     else column 
                end
```

Comment: Thank you..but what should i type in else part to not to change other cases. i like to set the defined states and ignore the else part. if i doesn't specify what else should do, it sets them NULL

Comment: the reason y i edited eldse part is the same reason that if there is not match of conditions it will update  NULL so i have updated the same value i.e colummn in else condition..

Comment: but i want the rest of values to stay still and don't change to NULL

Comment: That is y i have given column in else part

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`, like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE one
SET column = SUBSTRING('zyxwvutsrqpo', CHARINDEX(col, 'abcdefghijkl'), 1)
```

The idea is to find the index of `col` in a string of old letters, and pick an item from a new sequence at the same index. `'a'` would be mapped to `'z'`, `'b'` would be mapped to `'y'`, and so on.

If the sequence of replacement letters is the backward sequence of Latin letters, you could do it with `UNICODE` and `CHAR` pair of functions, too:

```
UPDATE TABLE one
SET column = CHAR(UNICODE('z')-UNICODE(col)+UNICODE('a'))
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcabc/6)